# Child model attributes are not translated in error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Let's say I have two models, `Discussion` and `Comment`.

```
class Discussion < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  validates :title, presence: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :discussion
  validates :link, presence: true
  validates :body, presence: true
end
```

activerecord.yml:

```
sv:
  attributes:
    body: Text
  activerecord:
    models:
      comment:
        one: Kommentar
        other: Kommentarer
    attributes:
      comment:
        link: Länk
```

Now, when I create a discussion with a comment and I don't fill in the `Link` or the `Body`, the attribute name in the error message for `Body`.

It looks like this:

```
- Text måste anges
- Comments link måste anges
```

Why is only `Body` translated, which is specified at the top of the locale file and not `Link` which is translated in the comment section of the locale file?

Comment: IMHO your setup should work. Although I am not sure why the `body: Text` spec is outside of the activerecord scope. Have you tried validating an invalid comment model directly, without the discussion?

Comment: I have several models with a `body` attribute and I want to translate them all to `Text`. If I put it like this it applies to all models which have a `body` attribute. If I validate a `Comment` model separately it is translated correctly.